# Adjusting EPS figure text

Tags: graphics, eps

I've got a series of EPS figures in my LaTeX article which each contain some title texts and labels. I would like to adjust these texts according to the text font type and size in my article, making one uniform document. How can I achieve this within LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This is something for `psfrag` -- put this won't work (at least I think so) with `pdflatex` then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think with `pstool` you can.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Ah, `pstool` -- never used it before